# Calculation Errors in while loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, object

I have gotten this to work nicely, but when speed hits a certain speed it want it to stay that speed and not increase. The code does this to an extent, but when I am printing out the values one the the values hit 270 and then drops back down to 250. I do not want it so surpass 250 ever. Also the decent variable keeps moving up should it not stay the same value when max speed is hit or is this right and it is behaving right it just looks wrong to me? What I am getting at is should the distance traveled be more if the object has hit terminal velocity which i set to 250 every second ? Or do I have to set up the code differntly? Like have an if statement in there to say if mySpeed = maxSpeed then only use a certian decent rate? Well this is straight out of a physics book so...
Thanks for any help

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;

    namespace JumpSimR
    {
      class Program
      {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //non modifiable constants
        const double maxSpeed = 250; //terminal velocity
        const double g = 32.17; //imeriial unity feet per sec g = dv/dt

        //variablbes used for player
        double mySpeed;         //current spped of person
        double myAlt;           //altitude of the person
        double myDist;          //distance travled for jump
        double t;               //time in simulation
        //parachute variables
        bool deploy;
        bool lCord;
        bool rCord;


        double alt;

        //get the alttitude from user input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Jump Altitued:");
        Console.WriteLine("a for 30000 Ft");
        Console.WriteLine("b for 25000 Ft");
        Console.WriteLine("c for 15000 Ft");
        String alt1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (alt1.Equals("a"))
        {
            alt = 30000;
        }
        else if (alt1.Equals("b"))
        {
            alt = 25000;
        }
        else { alt = 15000; }
        Console.WriteLine("The Hight of the jump is " + alt);

        myAlt = alt; //assign player alt to jump hight
        t = 1;
        mySpeed = 0;
        deploy = false;

        while(myAlt > 0)
        {
            if (maxSpeed > mySpeed){
                mySpeed = g * t;
            }
            else if (mySpeed >= maxSpeed) 
            {
                mySpeed = maxSpeed;
            }

            myDist = mySpeed * t; //distace = velocity * time

            if (0 > myAlt - myDist) { myAlt = 0; } else { myAlt -= myDist; } //subtract distance travled from starting alt
            Console.WriteLine("My Speed: " + mySpeed);
            Console.WriteLine("My Distance: " + myDist);
            Console.WriteLine("Altitude: " + myAlt);
            t++;

        }

        // keep screen from going away
        // when run from VS.NET
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
        }
```

Comment: Can we label this as `homework`?

Comment: @JonathanM Well it seems to be :)

Comment: No it is not I am working on a game where the player jumps out of a plane I just need to work out the physics before I put it into xna. Its easier in number than to do it buy guseing where the model is.

Comment: myDist is wrong too, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the else, you were allowing it to pass the max for that one iteration:

```
        if (maxSpeed > mySpeed){
            mySpeed = g * t;
        }
        if (mySpeed >= maxSpeed) 
        {
            mySpeed = maxSpeed;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the max speed issue, your distance calculation is also wrong. You made kind of the opposite mistake I did in my original answer, you do not account for acceleration.

```
myDist = mySpeed * t; //distace = velocity * time
```

needs to be changed to

```
myDist += mySpeed; //Old distance + current time slice's speed;
```

If you did not have changing acceleration you could have used the X<sub>t</sub> = X<sub>0</sub> + V<sub>0</sub>t + (1/2)at<sup>2</sup> fomula, but since a changes (it goes from 32.17 to 0 once `mySpeed >= maxSpeed`) so you must sum up the current position using each time slices current speed.

---

**The below is wrong**, it does not account for the acceleration changing terminal velocity, I am leaving it here though as it is a useful lesson

Along with the errors about the max speed people have posted some of your algorithms are wrong.

the formula for position is
X<sub>t</sub> = X<sub>0</sub> + V<sub>0</sub>t + (1/2)at<sup>2</sup> and the formula for velocity is v<sub>t</sub> = v<sub>0</sub>t + a

V<sub>0</sub> = 0 and X<sub>0</sub> = `alt` for your game so your code can be simplified to

```
while(myAlt > 0)
{
    myAlt = alt + .5 * g * t * t; // Starting Velocity was 0 so we left it out.
    mySpeed = g * t; // Starting Velocity was 0 so we left it out.
    Console.WriteLine("My Speed: " + mySpeed);
    Console.WriteLine("My Distance: " + (alt - myAlt));
    Console.WriteLine("Altitude: " + myAlt);
    t++;

}
```

---

P.S. If there is nothing more to process I find Debugger.Break() is more useful than Console.ReadLine() for keeping the program from closing.

Comment: Ah thank that is very useful I will have to work back though it again to see about my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the new `mySpeed` *after* checking if it is less than the maximum speed - you should do this calculation *before* that. To simplify your code you can also use `Math.Min()` instead of your `if` checks:

```
mySpeed =  g * t;
mySpeed  = Math.Min(maxSpeed, mySpeed);
```